# Mutiple XML blocks in the same file export via bash

Tags: xml, bash

I have an XML file that contains a bunch of separate code blocks. Each one needs to be within its own file... Each one starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and ends with `</endxml>`. Is there a way with BASH that I can take this single file and make each one of the code blocks above its own file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `</endxml>` is guaranteed to be on a separate line by itself, you can try this one (not necessarily the best possible):

```
awk 'BEGIN {nout=1;} /^<\/endxml>$/ {close("xml"nout".xml"); ++nout;} !/^<\/endxml>$/ {print >("xml"nout".xml");}'
```

It will create files `xml1.xml`, `xml2.xml` and so on. The `</endxml>` line is removed, and the XML header is retained.

Comment: I seem to get the following error: awk file.xml makes too many open files